# loading keras model issues warning: skipping variable loading for optimizer 'Adam'

Tags: keras

I save a keras model with
`model.save("folder/file.keras")`
Then I load this model with
`model = load_model("folder/file.keras")`
Everything loads and runs except I get a warning:
`WARNING:absl:Skipping variable loading for optimizer 'Adam', because it has 111 variables whereas the saved optimizer has 1 variables.`
Keras docs say that keras model.save saves optimizer state so I would expect to load it up just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

check that you didn't load model that was saved before fit was called with it even once